How to uninstall Microsoft Edge from Windows 11?
How can I completely uninstall Microsoft Edge from Windows 11?

I have already disabled the three services mentioned in the answer to this question.
I do not mind if any programs that rely on Microsoft Edge stop working. That won't be a problem.


You can uninstall it from the Installed apps list in Settings (this also mentions other methods)

press/click the windows key (left-bottom corner),
click the Settings icon
click on Installed apps
locate Microsoft Edge
click on the three dots next to Microsft Edge
click on Uninstal

The website using this shows this in visual steps.

This answer would benefit from further fleshing out with the steps required to do so. How to do so in Settings? Where is Installed Apps located at? How to get to it? etc. Without this, it's more of a comment, not an answer.

Thanks for this. That's the normal method for uninstalling a program on MSW11, and for MS Edge it doesn't work because the Uninstall option is greyed out. Marshall Gunnell's recommended method culminating in "Setup –uninstall –force-uninstall –system-level" didn't work either. His second method, which involves changing a registry key, looked promising, because it ungreys the Uninstall option. But when I changed the registry key, clicked on Uninstall, and restarted, unfortunately MS Edge was still there and opened in the normal way after "msedge".

Another method I've tried is to delete the directory "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge*" from safe mode, using a CLI. This too seemed to be promising, in that the command was accepted and the directory seemed to have been deleted, but when I restarted in normal mode and went "msedge", MS Edge opened!

@tell - You have verified your method actually works? Because Microsoft Edge can only be removed on systems marked to be within the EU region at this time. The duplicate has a method that can be used on any system to take advantage of that fact. What I can say is that on Windows 11 23H2, Microsoft Edge is located, within Installed apps but the option to uninstall it is grayed out

@Ramhound - I haven't found a method that works yet. Is the method to which you refer in your third sentence the one that involves installing ViVeTool? Taras Buria says "You need this app to enable a hidden feature currently rolling out to Insiders." But how do I know I can trust that program? For the record, the "Name" value of the said reg key on my installation of 23H2 is "GB". Wait...I will try the method you give in your answer...

@Ramhound - Thank you! Your method works, and I didn't have to install ViVeTool.

@tell - Modifying a file responsible for determining if the system is in the EU, allows for Edge and other built-in applications, to be uninstalled. ViVeTool was only required back when I submitted the answer.

Doesn't work for me. There is indeed the Uninstall link, it prompts up a root-level confirmation, but after confirming it doesn't do anything at all.
